# com.google.zxing.NotFoundException while using zxing to decode qrcode

Tags: java, zxing

We are using zxing to decode qrcode from images, most of qrcode could normally be extracted from the original images, but some not. I will show the decoder codes and shall we together discuss about what causes NotFoundException and find out solutions.

First of all, need some zxing dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
  <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then see the detail codes:

```
 public static String decodeQrCode(BufferedImage image) throws DependencyServiceException
{
    // Convert the image to a binary bitmap source
    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    // Decode the barcode
    QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
    Result result = null;
    try
    {
        result = reader.decode(bitmap);
    }
    catch (NotFoundException | ChecksumException | FormatException e)
    {
        throw new DependencyServiceException(e);
    }
    return result == null ? null : result.getText();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File file = new File("/tmp/ivan_qr_code.jpg");
    String qrCodeOriginUrlExtracted = "";
    try
    {
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);

        String qrCodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
        BufferedImage image = Base64StringToImageUtil.generateImageFromString(qrCodeBase64);
        qrCodeOriginUrlExtracted = QrCodeDecoderUtil.decodeQrCode(image);
        imageInFile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Extracted text from qr code: %1$s", qrCodeOriginUrlExtracted));
}
```

Errors generated:

```
Exception in thread "main"  {"errorCode": "3000", "debugInfo":"null","message": "com.google.zxing.NotFoundException"}
at com.waijule.common.util.image.QrCodeDecoderUtil.decodeQrCode(QrCodeDecoderUtil.java:44)
at com.waijule.common.util.image.QrCodeDecoderUtil.main(QrCodeDecoderUtil.java:58)
```

Caused by: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

The template qr code provided as following:

[image]

Thanks for all the little helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the whole, the decode method depends on the specific circumstance, DecodeHintType and barcode reader need to specify in advance. Refer to the open source of https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx from [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/zxingorg/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/web/DecodeServlet.java), pay attention to the method 'processImage'.

Thanks for the followers these days.